# OpportunityLineItem table is empty?

Tags: soql

I am trying to get a list of products on a specific account. I can go into the SFDC dashboard and see that this account has 10 products on it, but when I try to query for those products I get nothing. Eventually, I wanted to see if the `OpportunityLineItem` table had *anything* and I used this query:

```
select id, quantity, unitPrice, totalPrice, opportunity.name, opportunity.amount
    from OpportunityLineItem 
    where opportunity.stageName = 'Closed'
```

and even this:

```
select id from OpportunityLineItem
```

Both returned no rows for results. Is there something I can do to rebuild this database so I can actually get the list of products associated with an account via the SOQL?

Comment: If these products are directly related to an account (ie, theres a related list under the account where you can see records) they're probably not `OppLineItem`'s, they're probably a custom object.

Comment: @battery.cord good point. I think thats exactly what this is. I will follow-up once I confirm